# Take Only color codes as input

Tags: javascript, string, colors

I will take string from the variable and it will only accept the colour codes of any type like rgba, hashcode and rgb etc. so how can i create that variable that only accept this type of inputs?

i want this solution in javascript.

Comment: so write a validation to validate the input

Comment: What did you try so far where is the problem in your code?
Add your code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , i can do that , here is solution for that

```js
const str = "This is a #FF0000 red color text and #0000FF blue color text.";
const regex = /#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}\b|\b(?:rgb|hsl)a?\((?:(?:\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d)(?:\s*,\s*)){2}(?:\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d)(?:\s*\/\s*(?:0\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)/g;
const hexColors = str.match(regex);
console.log(hexColors);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS support API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports)

You can use this API to validate the input

```
CSS.supports(propertyName, propertyValue)
```

```js
console.log(CSS.supports('color','blue') )
console.log(CSS.supports('color','#FFFFFF') )
console.log(CSS.supports('color','xyz') )
console.log(CSS.supports('color','rgb(0,0,0)') )
```